# 90/180-day rule: can I live in France essentially 6 months per year?

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, 90-180-visa-rules, long-term

Let’s assume that I have enough money to actually support this... I’m just curious.

I am an American citizen, and I really like France. Given the 90/180 day rule for tourist visas in the Schengen Zone, could I theoretically live in France for 90 days, return to the US for another 90 or so, then go back to France for another 90? Could I repeat this (theoretically) indefinitely?

If the law technically permits it and it’s legal, what reasons might immigration have for denying me entry anyway? Money? Too many/too long of visits? They don’t like my face?

Comment: France has a visa that allows non-EU citizens to stay for longer than 90 days if  they have sufficient funds to support themselves.

Comment: @Chris Cireface After a few visit cycles, it’s possible you could be questioned about the purpose of your repeated visits -‘justifiable purpose of stay’. As indeed you could be asked to explain this, plus show a return ticket and proof of sufficient funds, any time you request visa-free entry. Another reason could be if your passport did not have the required validity remaining before expiry https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages/France.html

Comment: @phoog do you have a link to the documentation for that visa? I’ve looked all over the internet and can’t find it =/

Comment: Remember that there is no obligation to let you enter. If immigration officer will think you are not a genuine tourist (or whatever reason you are traveling visa free), you can be denied, and so probably you lose the right to enter without visa. Note: other laws about staying more than 3 months could apply (social security, registration to a place, taxes, etc.)

Comment: One of the first questions that will come to the mind of the IO will probably be "how are you supporting yourself", which leads to questions about you actually working while you're there, which is of course not allowed on such a visa/visa waiver. Also, as pointed out by @GiacomoCatenazzi if you stay longer in France that in any other country (say you spend 6 months in France, 5 months in the US, and the rest in other countries), you may become tax resident in France, in which case you may have to declare your income and possibly pay taxes in France **and** in the US.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi there is no provision in the Schengen codes for visa-free visitors to lose visa-free status, which depends solely on nationality.  (This is in contrast, of course, to the US visa waiver program, in which some people can be disqualified from the VWP while remaining eligible to visit the US with a B visa.)  Chris: I am looking for the documentation.  It is indeed hard to find.  I should have something in a few minutes.

Comment: @jcaron US citizens are notoriously always liable to report and potentially pay taxes on their worldwide income, regardless of their residence, but they can either deduct or take a credit for taxes paid to other jurisdictions, so the additional administrative burden is likely to be the most significant problem here; the total tax burden may not be much higher.

Comment: @phoog Yes, I know, didn't want to go into too much detail as the chance of this happening in this situation remains quite small, so I just qualified it with "possibly" :-) I think the "how are you supporting yourself" part is the most important one here, unless of course OP has a big stash of money to support themselves without working.

Comment: @jcaron indeed.  Given the wording of the first sentence, it seems that the assumption that OP has "enough money to actually support this" may be counterfactual or at least questionable.  I do not know how likely it is actually to be questioned at the border.

Comment: Information about long-term visitor visas may be found at https://france-visas.gouv.fr.  Follow the link "do you need a visa."  Then choose "long-stay" for visa type and "France" for main destination, filling out the rest as appropriate. Click "Search." Then choose "familial or private establishment (adult)" for "your plans" and "visitor" for "main purpose of stay."  See also https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F16162 (under "de quoi s'agit-il," see *Visa de long séjour temporaire : valable 4 à 6 mois … comme visiteur).*  Questions about this belong on [Expatriates.SE].